# Maven doesn't run TestNG tests generated by groovy compiler

Tags: java, maven, groovy, testng

I have a java project with tests written in groovy.

I use TestNG as unit testing framework.

I also have several tests written in java.

After maven `test-compile` phase all tests (both groovy and java) are compiled and placed in the similar folder inside `target/test-classes/`.

When I want to run tests with maven, only java tests are run.

When I tried to run groovy test from the IDE (IntelliJ IDEA), it runs perfectly.

I decompiled groovy test and here is what I have:

```
package mypackage.core;

import groovy.lang.GroovyObject;
import groovy.lang.MetaClass;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test
public class Sample
  implements GroovyObject
{
  public Sample()
  {
    Sample this;
    CallSite[] arrayOfCallSite = $getCallSiteArray();
    this.metaClass = $getStaticMetaClass();
    MetaClass tmp20_17 = this.metaClass;
    this.metaClass = ((MetaClass)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(tmp20_17, $get$$class$groovy$lang$MetaClass()));
    tmp20_17;
    while (true)
      return;
  }

  @Test
  public void testSomething()
  {
    CallSite[] arrayOfCallSite = $getCallSiteArray(); Registry registry = arrayOfCallSite[0].callConstructor($get$$class$mypackage$core$internal$Registry());
    arrayOfCallSite[1].call(registry, null); for (return; ; return);
  }

  static
  {
     tmp10_7 = new Long(0L);
    __timeStamp__239_neverHappen1314379332415 = (Long)tmp10_7;
    tmp10_7;
     tmp28_25 = new Long(1314379332415L);
    __timeStamp = (Long)tmp28_25;
    tmp28_25;
    Class tmp48_45 = ((Class)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType($get$$class$mypackage$core$Sample(), $get$$class$java$lang$Class()));
    $ownClass = (Class)tmp48_45;
    tmp48_45;
    return;
    while (true)
      return;
  }
}
```

Has anyone met similar issue? What can be wrong here?
Can it be connected with the fact that class `Sample` implements `GroovyObject`? Can it be connected with bad surefire version?

Thanks!

**UPD:**
Groovy-related settings in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven.runtime</groupId>
   <artifactId>gmaven-runtime-1.6</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
...
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <goals>
            <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
            <goal>testCompile</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Groovy tests are placed in `mymodule/src/test/groovy/..`, java tests are placed in `mymodule/src/test/java/..`.

After `test-compile` phase they both are in `mymodule/target/test-classes/..`.

I don't have special section for surefire in my `pom.xml`, but from looking at local repository `.m2` I can say that surefire plugin of version `2.4.3` is being used.

Comment: what folder are your groovy tests in? What does your groovy compiler settings in pom.xml look like? What does your surefire config in pom.xml look like?

Comment: @matt b: see upd section pls.

Comment: Did you try renaming the Test classes?

Comment: @h3xStream: I'll try just out of curiosity, but even if it works, it's not a solution. Tests which are written in java works fine as they are. Tests which are written in groovy are ommited. Both are compiled to a pretty similar byte code.

Comment: @h3xStream: as I mentioned in the post, the problem is probably connected with maven, because everything works fine under IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Also I believe you need to tell surefire where the test source directory is with it's `testSourceDirectory` property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test classes must end with "Test" in order to be selected by maven test phase. Just rename the class to SampleTest.

Comment: your suggestion really works. I still hope to find a better solution, but yours will be a fallback.

Comment: an interesting moment: until I removed `@Test` annotation from the test class, all its methods (like different `notify`s) were treated as tests as well as my special method annotated with `@Test`.

Comment: This behavior might be link to the default inclusion for Java test cases : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

Comment: that's a nice point. I'll try the option with regexp (as it's done over class files).